# Triple UNION SQL query running really slow

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I have 4 tables, one of them, "BEOORDELING", is a grouping table of the other three (see image structure). The query takes a long time (10 seconds). Can this query be simplified to a faster performance? It seems the left joins are repeated on each select. Should I be using methods other than unions?

```
SELECT 
  BM_PUNTENBLAD_FK AS BO_PUNTENBLAD_FK, 
  BO_ID, 
  BO_TYPE, 
  BO_BEOORDELINGMOMENT_FK, 
  BO_VAKBEOORDELING_FK, 
  BO_BEOORDELINGBEREKENING_FK, 
  EV_ID, 
  BM_CODE, 
  BM_OMSCHRIJVING, 
  BM_DATUM, 
  BM_NOEMER, 
  BM_GEWICHT, 
  BM_GEWENST, 
  BM_TYPE, 
  BM_EVALUATIEVERWIJZING_FK, 
  BM_PUBLICATIEDATUM, 
  BM_CATEGORIE_FK, 
  BM_QUOTATIELIJST_FK, 
  NULL AS VB_CODE, 
  NULL AS VB_OMSCHRIJVING, 
  NULL AS VB_QUOTATIELIJST_FK, 
  NULL AS VB_TYPE_FKP, 
  NULL AS VB_EVALUATIEVERWIJZING_FK, 
  NULL AS BB_CODE, 
  NULL AS BB_OMSCHRIJVING, 
  NULL AS BB_TYPE_FKP, 
  NULL AS BB_FLAGS, 
  NULL AS BB_EVALUATIEVERWIJZING_FK, 
  NULL AS BB_CATEGORIE_FK, 
  NULL AS BB_NEEDSRECALCULATION 
FROM 
  BEOORDELINGMOMENT 
  LEFT JOIN BEOORDELING ON (BM_ID = BO_BEOORDELINGMOMENT_FK) 
  LEFT JOIN EVALUATIEVERWIJZING ON (
    BM_EVALUATIEVERWIJZING_FK = EV_ID
  ) 
WHERE 
  (0 = 1) 
UNION 
SELECT 
  VB_PUNTENBLAD_FK AS BO_PUNTENBLAD_FK, 
  BO_ID, 
  BO_TYPE, 
  BO_BEOORDELINGMOMENT_FK, 
  BO_VAKBEOORDELING_FK, 
  BO_BEOORDELINGBEREKENING_FK, 
  EV_ID, 
  NULL AS BM_CODE, 
  NULL AS BM_OMSCHRIJVING, 
  NULL AS BM_DATUM, 
  NULL AS BM_NOEMER, 
  NULL AS BM_GEWICHT, 
  NULL AS BM_GEWENST, 
  NULL AS BM_TYPE, 
  NULL AS BM_EVALUATIEVERWIJZING_FK, 
  NULL AS BM_PUBLICATIEDATUM, 
  NULL AS BM_CATEGORIE_FK, 
  NULL AS BM_QUOTATIELIJST_FK, 
  VB_CODE, 
  VB_OMSCHRIJVING, 
  VB_QUOTATIELIJST_FK, 
  VB_TYPE_FKP, 
  VB_EVALUATIEVERWIJZING_FK, 
  NULL AS BB_CODE, 
  NULL AS BB_OMSCHRIJVING, 
  NULL AS BB_TYPE_FKP, 
  NULL AS BB_FLAGS, 
  NULL AS BB_EVALUATIEVERWIJZING_FK, 
  NULL AS BB_CATEGORIE_FK, 
  NULL AS BB_NEEDSRECALCULATION 
FROM 
  VAKBEOORDELING 
  LEFT JOIN BEOORDELING ON (VB_ID = BO_VAKBEOORDELING_FK) 
  LEFT JOIN EVALUATIEVERWIJZING ON (
    VB_EVALUATIEVERWIJZING_FK = EV_ID
  ) 
UNION 
SELECT 
  BB_PUNTENBLAD_FK AS BO_PUNTENBLAD_FK, 
  BO_ID, 
  BO_TYPE, 
  BO_BEOORDELINGMOMENT_FK, 
  BO_VAKBEOORDELING_FK, 
  BO_BEOORDELINGBEREKENING_FK, 
  EV_ID, 
  NULL AS BM_CODE, 
  NULL AS BM_OMSCHRIJVING, 
  NULL AS BM_DATUM, 
  NULL AS BM_NOEMER, 
  NULL AS BM_GEWICHT, 
  NULL AS BM_GEWENST, 
  NULL AS BM_TYPE, 
  NULL AS BM_EVALUATIEVERWIJZING_FK, 
  NULL AS BM_PUBLICATIEDATUM, 
  NULL AS BM_CATEGORIE_FK, 
  NULL AS BM_QUOTATIELIJST_FK, 
  NULL AS VB_CODE, 
  NULL AS VB_OMSCHRIJVING, 
  NULL AS VB_QUOTATIELIJST_FK, 
  NULL AS VB_TYPE_FKP, 
  NULL AS VB_EVALUATIEVERWIJZING_FK, 
  BB_CODE, 
  BB_OMSCHRIJVING, 
  BB_TYPE_FKP, 
  BB_FLAGS, 
  BB_EVALUATIEVERWIJZING_FK, 
  BB_CATEGORIE_FK, 
  BB_NEEDSRECALCULATION 
FROM 
  BEOORDELINGBEREKENING 
  LEFT JOIN BEOORDELING ON (
    BB_ID = BO_BEOORDELINGBEREKENING_FK
  ) 
  LEFT JOIN EVALUATIEVERWIJZING ON (
    BB_EVALUATIEVERWIJZING_FK = EV_ID
  )
```

[image]

Comment: How long do the individual queries take by themselves?

Comment: If you don't need to remove duplicates between the queries, use `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Why `WHERE 
  (0 = 1)`?

Comment: On the select queries, have you done an EXPLAIN on them to determine if indexing is sufficient? That's where I would start.

Answer (score 0):

The first select expression can be left out, because it makes zero sense to have that select in there, as the `WHERE (0 = 1)` means that it produces zero rows.

Changing `UNION` to `UNION ALL` will improve performance because it will not try to remove duplicates (which given the population of the columns is probably not a concern).

Depending on your needs, and the actual population of data, replacing `LEFT JOIN` with an `INNER JOIN` could also lead to improvements, but it might leave out rows.

Without DDL of the tables, constraints and their indices, and example data, it is hard to guess at other improvements. You might also want to check if your database has (up-to-date) statistics for the indices.

Comment: Thanks, i left out the quere for where (0=1) it improved a bit, not too much. When the db is in my computer the time it takes the query is around 3 secs, but when i access the db remotely, it goes up to 8 seconds..

Comment: @TonathiuRedrovan How many rows does the query produce? Are there any blob fields in the query?

Comment: Like 32000 I believe